# Cache LINQ query - IEnumerable.Skip()

Tags: c#, linq

Consider the following code

```
IEnumerable<Items> remainingItems = Items
var results = new List<List<Items>>();
var counter = 0;
while (remainingItems.Any())
{
    var result = new List<Item>();
    result.AddRange(remainingItems.TakeWhile(x => somePredicate(x, counter));
    results.Add(result);
    remainingItems = remainingItems.Skip(result.Count);
    counter++;
}
```

If it's not clear whats happening, I'm taking an Ienumerable, and iterating through it till a predicate fails, putting all those items into one pile, and then continue iterating through the remaining items till the next predicate fails, and put all of those in a pile. Rinse, Wash, Repeat.

Now the bit I want to focus on here is the Ienumerable.Skip()

Since it uses delayed execution, it means I have to go through all the elements I've already skipped on each loop.

I could use ToList() to force it to evaluate, but then it needs to iterate through all the remaining items to do so, which is just as bad.

So what I really need is an IEnumerable, which does the skipping eagerly, and stores the first last point we were up to, to continue from there. So I need some function like:

`IEnumerable.SkipAndCache(n)` which allows me to access an IEnumerator starting at the nth item.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are enumerating multiple times the same enumerable. It is bad from here. Change the algorithm to be a single `foreach`

Comment: "which allows me to access an IEnumerator starting at the nth item" That´s exactly what `Skip` does. It returns an enumerator beginning at the first index that is greater the number of elements to be skipped.

Comment: @HimBromBeere yes. But it does so by going through all the other items first each time. I need it to store that item.

Comment: You might be better off using .GetEnumerator(), and doing the iteration yourself.

Comment: Then force your code to be immediately evaluated by calling `ToList`. That will iterate the entire collection exactly *once*, not on any call to `Enumerator.MoveNext` (e.g. by calling `Any`, `TakeWhile` or `Skip`, making **three** iterations to the collection).

Comment: @HimBromBeere Thats even worse, as it requires iterating through all the remaining items in the list

Comment: Yeah, but only once, not thrice.

Comment: Why not use a simple `IEnumerator`? That's pure `SkipAndCache`, if you will, because it can only move forward.

Comment: Can you please clarify, by "putting all those items into one pile" do you mean all the items since the last failure, as well as the current failure, should go into a collection? E.g. numbers ending in 0 or 5 are 'fails', so you would get the collections [0], [1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10], etc.

Comment: @p3tch indeed that is the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) for that. There is an experimental function called `Memoize` which lazily caches the sequence. So the code will look like this:

```
while (remainingItems.Any())
{
    var result = new List<Item>();
    result.AddRange(remainingItems.TakeWhile(x => somePredicate(x, counter));
    results.Add(result);
    remainingItems = remainingItems.Skip(result.Count).Memoize();
    counter++;
}
```

Here the result will not be materialized because it is still lazy evaluation:

```
remainingItems = remainingItems.Skip(result.Count).Memoize();
```

Here the `remainingItems` sequence will be evaluated and cached (the iterator will not go through all the elements like in `ToList`):

```
remainingItems.Any()
```

And here the cache will be used:

```
result.AddRange(remainingItems.TakeWhile(x => somePredicate(x, counter));
```

To use this method you need to add:

```
using MoreLinq.Experimental;
```

Answer (score 0):

As we are skipping the result set in series why not use the for loop for the same like

```
 for(int i = 0 ; i < result.Count ; i++){
       //do some business logic and now i got X result
      i = i + X
    }
```

Comment: True. But the SkipAndCache is useful for some other code I'm writing as well, so i'd be interested in seeing an implementation

Answer (score 0):

Yield might be useful, if I'm understanding your question correctly

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Test<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    var items = new List<T>();

    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        items.Add(item);

        if (!SomePredicate(item))
        {
            yield return items;
            items = new List<T>();
        }
    }

    // if you want any remaining items to go into their own IEnumerable, even if there's no more fails
    if (items.Count > 0)
    {
        yield return items;
    }
}
```

Just as en example I made my fail condition to be `!item % 10 == 0` and passed in values 0 to 1000 to the above method. I get 101 IEnumerables containing 0 in the first, and the rest containing 1 to 10, 11 to 20, etc. etc.

Comment: This does something completely different than the originally posted code. Just try it with `int[]{100}`as input and `i<counter` as predicate and see whether you get 101 empty lists and one list containing just one element (`100`)

Comment: @Haukinger read the latest 2 comments on the OP, this solution does exactly that. If you want to add a counter and check if the current value is equal, less than, or greater than - go ahead, it still works. I'm not even sure what you mean by `i<counter` because surely `i` *is* your counter?

Comment: The OP passes the item (`i`) into the predicate and the counter of the loop (`counter`). And it produces empty items in the result array if there's more than one item with failing predicate in a row.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple extension method to help with this:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> PartitionBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Func<T, int, bool> predicate)
{
    var block = new List<T>();
    int index = 0;

    foreach (var item in sequence)
    {
        if (predicate(item, index++))
        {
            block.Add(item);
        }
        else if (block.Count > 0)
        {
            yield return block.ToList(); // Return a copy so the caller can't change our local list.
            block.Clear();
        }
    }

    if (block.Count > 0)
        yield return block; // No need for a copy since we've finished using our local list.
}
```

(As an extension method, you need to put that in a static class.)

Then you can use it to partition data like so. For this example, we will partition a list of ints into partitions where the list element's value is equal to its index:

```
static void Main()
{                         //  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
    var ints = new List<int> {0, 1, 0, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 8, 9};

    var result = ints.PartitionBy(((item, index) => item == index)); // Items where value == index.

    foreach (var seq in result)
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", seq));

    // Output is:
    // 0, 1
    // 3, 4, 5
    // 8, 9
}
```

Note that this implementation skips over elements that do not match the predicate.

---

Here's an alternative, more complicated implementation that doesn't make a copy of the data:

```
class Indexer
{
    public int  Index;
    public bool Finished;
}

public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> PartitionBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Func<T, int, bool> predicate)
{
    var iter = sequence.GetEnumerator();
    var indexer = new Indexer();

    while (!indexer.Finished)
    {
        yield return nextBlock(iter, predicate, indexer);
    }
}

static IEnumerable<T> nextBlock<T>(IEnumerator<T> iter, Func<T, int, bool> predicate, Indexer indexer)
{
    int index = indexer.Index;
    bool any = false;

    while (true)
    {
        if (!iter.MoveNext())
        {
            indexer.Finished = true;
            yield break;
        }

        if (predicate(iter.Current, index++))
        {
            any = true;
            yield return iter.Current;
        }
        else
        {
            indexer.Index = index;

            if (any)
                yield break;
        }
    }
}
```